# ssh reverse tunnel port forwarding connection fails

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, port-forwarding, tunneling

I am able to do a reverse port forwarding through the PUTTY GUI with settings similar to below. Once I apply this setting, I am able to run to the server box and run `wget http://localhost:8080` <-- a quick and dirty way to verify that the port is being forwarded.

[image: Image with GUI settings which WORKS.]

However **I am unable to make it working when I am using the command line**.

--

When I tried using the most basic reverse port forwarding commands in ssh, it just does not work

the few examples which I have tried

```
ssh -R 8080:localhost:80 root@debian-tunnel-a1
ssh -g -R 8080:localhost:80 root@debian-tunnel-a1 
ssh -f -g -R *:8080:localhost:80 root@debian-tunnel-a1 -p 22
```

Basically I've tried all samples I can find online for the past two days and they all don't work.

If I use the most commonly used commands which I've show above, I always get the error in the picture below:

[image]

As I try use a basic `wget http://localhost:8080`  On the SERVER machine (I am using wget `http://localhost:8080` as a way to verify that Device #1 's port 80 is being forwarded to the Server device #2's port 8080, and that I can access it directly),
the device #1 which I use the reverse port command basically spit out this error above.

It seems like the connection LINK is established, but the reverse port machine is not allowing it to go through.  But the puzzling thing is I am able to get it working under GUI, but just not command line.

---

To have a full picture of what the goal is:

device #1 share port 80 to------> server device #2 --------->  device #3 (talks to device #1 through server with server being the middleman)

I am still stuck on the first portion of  (device #1 ---> server device #2)   once I am completed, then I will   relay device #1  to  device #3  with server device #2 acting as middleman.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to do? What runs where and how do you want to connect?

Comment: When you try to set this up via a command line are you doing it on the same machine on which the putty runs? From your error screenshot it seems that you are trying to create a tunnel on the server itself.

Comment: The ultimate goal is   (device #1 reverse port tunnel through port) ---> (server device #2 receives the reverse port acting as localhost:8080) ---> (finally device #3 using -L to get that localhost:8080 and run it locally on device #3)

Comment: I am still confused, what do you actually want to achieve.. maybe a drawing / diagram would help me?

Comment: updated diagram http://s22.postimg.org/b2jfgawup/diagram_ssh_tunnel_a1.png